# Formatting ComboBox based on the length of string

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I'm trying to format the length of a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn based on the length of the longest string in the comboBox. Here is the code I currently have, but it only formats the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn based on the users previous selection in the comboBox.

Is there a way to have the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn at the length of the longest string in the comboBox?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub comboTest_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles comboTest.SelectionChangeCommitted

    Dim senderComboBox As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)

    'Change the length of the text box depending on what the user has
    'selected and committed using the SelectionLength property.
    If (comboTest.SelectionLength > 0) Then
        comboTest.Width = comboTest.SelectionLength * CType(Me.comboTest.Font.SizeInPoints, Integer)
        comboTest.SelectedValue = comboTest.SelectedText
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you just need to calculate the longest string in the `ComboBox`.  Assuming that it's just a collection of `String` values being displayed you can do the following.

```
Dim length = 0
For Each item As String in comboTest.Items 
  length = Max(length, item.Length)
Next

If length > 0 Then
  comboTest.Width = length * CType(Me.comboTest.Font.SizeInPoints, Integer)
  comboTest.SelectedValue = comboTest.SelectedText
End If
```

Comment: This is my code:                                                                                Dim length = 0 For Each item As String In markCode.Items length = Max(length, item.Length) Next If length > 0 Then markCode.Width = length * CType(Me.markCode.Font.SizeInPoints, Integer) markCode.SelectedValue = markCode.SelectedText End If The error im receiving here is 'selectedValue is not a member of systems.windows.forms.dataGridViewComboBoxColum' Any Ideas?

Comment: sorry about the formatting in the above message, i honestly dont know how to format my comments properly, im new to this forum...

Comment: @user765942 To format comments use the `\`` operator around the code. I don't believe that type supports `SelectedValue` hence you're getting the error.  Have you checked MSDN to see what it supports here?

Comment: Thanks that worked for me used with a `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`. In my case I had to take the `Font` property from `comboTest.DataGridView.Font`. Just a little note, your snippet uses the `Max()` method which is part of the `Math` class. You should either import it or use `Math.Max(length, item.Length)`

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim length = 0
Dim maxlength = 0
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim g As Graphics = ComboBox2.CreateGraphics
Dim stringsize As New SizeF

For i = 0 To ComboBox2.Items.Count - 1
    ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = i
    stringsize = g.MeasureString((ComboBox2.GetItemText(ComboBox2.Items(i))), ComboBox2.Font)
    length = stringsize.Width
    If length > maxlength Then
        maxlength = length
    End If
Next i

Me.ComboBox2.Width = maxlength
```

Comment: Why did you answer something (without explanation of the answer) from something over 2 years old?

Comment: Sorry, I ran across the same issue and the popular answer above did not work 100% for me so I had to do it differently and this was my solution.  I know it's old but this should work and takes into account the font size as well.

Comment: I agree went w/ this approach of using Graphics class instead - was more accurate